# What the best XNA blog?

Tags: xna, blogs

I know good general programming blogs (like coding horror ;) ).
But I want very good specific XNA blog.
Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Shawn Hargreaves](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnhar/) and [Nick Gravelyn](http://nickgravelyn.com/) are two names that I run across a lot when looking for information on XNA.

It's not as much of a blog, but [Ziggyware](http://www.ziggyware.com/news.php) also has a lot of great information.

And you can also find helpful information right on the [XNA forums](http://forums.xna.com/forums/) and [GameDev.net forums](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/forum.asp?forum_id=10).

Oh, also, I like to read [Gamasutra](http://www.gamasutra.com/), which has articles from people developing on XNA.

Answer (score 5):

I really like [Shawn Hargreaves](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnhar) blog.  He has a lot of code examples and shows a lot of best practices and tricks to help development.

Answer (score 4):

You can start from www.creatorsclubonline.com , they have a huge list of links to XNA specific blogs. (not sure if you are looking at beginner level or advanced level blogs)

Meanwhile here are some...

http://blogs.msdn.com/etayrien/

http://www.xnatutorial.com/

http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials.shtml

http://www.xnatutorial.com/

http://www.phstudios.com/?q=node/16

best

Answer (score 1):

It depends what it is you expect from a blog. If you're searching for knowledge and techniques, you'd be grazy not to spend some time at [Riemer's](http://www.riemers.net/) tutorials as well!