# Newbie at XNA, general questions

Tags: c#, object, xna, user-input, collision

As the title points out, I'm relatively new at XNA. However, I've been given a trivial assignment by my boss to see if I can get it done. I have no doubt that I eventually will, but some pointers in the right direction would help.

This isn't a homework assignment, and I'm just looking for a couple of tips and pointers so I don't have to dig too deep into all the documentation just yet ;)

- How would I go about adding camera viewpoints to my project?
- What would be the best way to handle user input (keyboard in this case)
- Best practices/commonly used methods for detecting collision detection between two objects?

Also I must note that I'm coming from a C++ background, and C# is fairly new to me (although I've done some small projects, such as this one, before). Any help on the transition process between those two languages is appreciated as well.

Comment: Download the DirectX/XNA SDK - it comes with plenty of sample code. Great place to start!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, without knowing anything about your project (2D or 3D, for example), I can only point you in the direction of some websites where you can easily find specific information on these topics.  Check out this previous question about good [XNA blogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661249/what-the-best-xna-blog/687761), because most of the websites listed there will be good places for you to search for information on whatever you are trying to do (with lots of examples).

As far as moving from C++ to C#, here are a couple resources that might help you with that:

- [C++ -> C#: What You Need to Know to Move from C++ to C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301520.aspx)
- [C# FAQ for C++ programmers](http://andymcm.com/csharpfaq.htm)

Answer (score 2):

check out this simple 3d tutorial, access to the different chapters is in the menu bar on the right.

http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/series1.php

it has simple terrain, keyboard, and camera angle information, all in full code and it takes about 2 hours to get through the whole thing. enjoy